# How to get credentials from Google-Calendar-API for an app that has many subdomains?

Tags: google-calendar-api, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have an application that's many subdomains, and amoung all, has 500 concurrent users. And I need integrate Google Calendar to my app, but Google deny  the use of wildcards (*) for subdomains.
And is not posible charge all URLs in Google Console. So, my  question is....

It's possible get credential from a API, where its URL hasn't subdomain, like [www.mycalendarwrapper.com](http://www.mycalendarwrapper.com) ?

This's the plan...

From one of my app URL like user1.myapp.com request the autorization to my API, then sends the same request to Google, if credentials not found then, my API return the OAuth Consent Screen URL to my app.
After user confirm de consent screen, I recive the callback response from Google in my API, and store the token in my API. Then centrelize the calendar managment into mi API.

I been reading the Google Calendar API, but i'm not sure if that is possible.

Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 0):

*From the Google docs*

> You must set two restrictions: the first restricts to the subdomain,
> and the second adds a wildcard for the path. Neither restriction has a
> trailing slash. For example:
>
> ```
> https://*.example.com
> https://*.example.com/*
> ```
>
> If your domain allows HTTP, you must add additional restrictions
> separately for the HTTP URLs.

See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions